# UWP: Weird vertical within a splitview pane with displaymode compactoverlay

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, splitview

I'm seeing a weird flickering vertical line gap in my Splitview pane, even when i explicitly set a background for the Grid in the pane. It only happens when the app is not in fullscreen mode

The DisplayMode of the pane is set on "CompactOverlay" and the splitview content is a frame with a CaptureElement in it.

I tried to take a screenshot, but it doesn't show the line ...
So i took a photo of it.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: sorry i can't  it's really alot of code to simulate the program i'm working on and and it might be only on specific screens

Comment: Since you cannot post any code, we're not able to find out your problem. Here is my suggestion, you can use `Live Visual Tree` and try to select this line to check what exactly is this line when your app is in runtime.

Comment: Ok thank you very much :)